# Holding shift and alt gives eyedropper

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I was working with shape layers in photoshop CC 2018. I selected the ellipse tool and held down <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> which should create a circle with a centre at the point from where I started dragging , but instead, the cursor changes to the eyedropper tool. Can someone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> after having started making the circle without releasing the mouse